# Why is my query inserting the same values when I have added a 'not exists' parameter that should avoid this from happening?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query should stop inserting values, as the not exists statement is satisfied (I have checked both tables) and matching incidents exist in both tables, any ideas why values are still being returned?
Here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO
    odwh_system.ead_incident_credit_control_s
(
    incident
)   
SELECT DISTINCT
    tp.incident
FROM 
    odwh_data.ead_incident_status_audit_s ei
    INNER JOIN odwh_data.ead_incident_s tp ON ei.incident=tp.incident
WHERE   
    ei.status = 6 
OR
    ei.status = 7 

AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            true
        FROM
            odwh_system.ead_incident_credit_control_s ead
        WHERE
            ead.incident = tp.incident
        )
AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            true
        FROM
            odwh_work.ead_incident_tp_s tp
        WHERE
            tp.incident = ei.incident
        );
```

Comment: Just a case of (AND/OR) operator precedence: `WHERE   
    ei.status = 6 
OR
    ei.status = 7 AND ...` **-->>** `WHERE   
    ei.status IN( 6, 7) AND ...`

Comment: BTW: you dont need the `odwh_data.ead_incident_status_audit_s ei` table's columns, just put it into an `EXISTS()` clause, together with the `IN(6,7)`, it can be combined with the SECON `EXISTS()`. This could possibly avoid the ugly `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- dont reuse table aliases
- use *sane* aliases
- avoid **AND/OR** conflicts; prefer `IN()`

---

```
INSERT INTO odwh_system.ead_incident_credit_control_s (incident)
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    tp.incident
FROM odwh_data.ead_incident_s dtp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM odwh_system.ead_incident_credit_control_s sic
        WHERE sic.incident = dtp.incident
        )
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM odwh_work.ead_incident_tp_s wtp
        JOIN odwh_data.ead_incident_status_audit_s dis ON wtp.incident = dis.incident AND dis.status IN (6 ,7)
        WHERE wtp.incident = dtp.incident
        );
```